# check if two keys have different values in a list of dictionaries

Tags: list, dictionary, python-3.6

I have a list of dictionaries

```
 [{'cat': array([-3.01740319e-02,  4.39191431e-01,  3.24975878e-01, 
 -2.81387717e-02,...]},{},{},{}], where each dictionary is of a different length.
```

Some of the keys in the dictionaries are the same and I would like to check if their corresponding values are unique or the same.

I have used .update to merge all dictionaries and then check, but then realised that this would overwrite some values and not show me if there are any different/same values.

```
final = {}
for d in temp_dict_array:
    final.update(d)
```

All I would need is a method of showing me that two keys in different dictionaries have either the same or different value, even just through a simple print statement.

Comment: Which part do you need help with: finding the keys they share, or comparing the values for the same key in 2 dictionaries?

Comment: @ScottHunter I'd need to compare the values for the same key in two different dictionaries. Sorry if I did not make this clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the keys that are in both dictionaries, then check the values that correspond to those keys.

Where d1 and d2 are 2 dictionaries you want to check.

```
matching_keys = [key for key in d1.keys() if key in d2]

for key in matching keys:

    if d1[key] == d2[key]:
        # They're the same
    else:
        # They're not the same
```

(untested code)

Answer (score 0):

```
if dict1[key] == dict2[key]:
    ...
```